# IE10+ "X" Button text box displays only part of content

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, internet-explorer-10

I've got a web form with textboxes, ASP.NET 4. When the page is opened, if data exists on record for those textboxes, the data is inserted by the page's code-behind.

In Internet Explorer 10+, if the data is long enough, part of the it will not display in the textbox. The full text appears after the user clicks in the textbox to edit.

Picture is below. Chrome on the left, IE10 on the right. You can see from the picture that the text is only half the length of the textbox.

I have tried the "::-ms-clear" CSS settings that hide the X icon, but they have no effect on this issue. Here's the CSS I've got set for it, pushed as far as possible:

```
::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

[image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O0nbv.jpg]

Comment: Check that you're not in compatibility mode or quirks mode. IE10 will display the `X` widget in all modes, but `::-ms-clear` only works in IE10 Standards mode, so you can't get rid of it in Compat or Quirks mode.

Comment: Maybe the CSS on the text box is acting odd in IE, a padding-right perhaps.